# Is there a way to automatically generate karma.conf.js with a grunt task?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I've been using a modified version of the gruntfile that comes with the Yeoman.io base angularjs generator, and the grunt-bower-install command is kind of handy for keeping my base index.html file up-to-date with bower dependencies.

However, when I do a bower install (package) --save and then grunt bower-install, my index.html updates, but my karma.conf.js does not update, meaning I need to manually add the new file to the list of files to load when karma runs the test suite (otherwise the injector fails trying to inject a nonexistent package).

Is there any easy-peasy way to add this to my grunt workflow? It's not the end of the world, but it is one of those easy-to-forget things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually came up with a solution for just this problem. Check out https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install/issues/35#issuecomment-32084805

```
'bower-install': {
  app: {
    src: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
    ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
  },
  test: {
    src: 'karma.conf.js',
    fileTypes: {
      js: {
        block: /(([\s\t]*)\/\/\s*bower:*(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/\/\s*endbower)/gi,
        detect: {
          js: /'.*\.js'/gi
        },
        replace: {
          js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please update the answer in relation to this [**github issue**](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep/issues/86#issuecomment-46070234) fix that you've commented. It may help someone someday :)